# How do I set which days are work days on the Kendo UI Scheduler?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I can't seem to get the Kendo UI Scheduler to stop treating Saturdays and Sundays as non-work days? I'd like to stop showing the gray for Saturdays and Sundays. How do I set which days are work days?

Answer (score 3):

You can set workWeekEnd to an integer value.  The default is 5, which is Friday.  Setting it to 6 will make Saturday appear as a workday, and 7 makes Sunday appear as such.

Example:

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    workWeekEnd: 6
});
```

Source:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler

Comment: Be aware, that for **Sunday** you have to set `workWeekEnd: 0`